# How to get two values of string in a single HashMap?

Tags: android, list, hashmap, key

Im new to Android.

What i need is?..
Can i get two string values in a single hashmap, its possible.
I have two hashmaps,these two hashmap values should i get in another hashmap. How to implement this? Any help.. Thanks in advance..

> ```
>                 String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
>                 System.out.println("Checking ::"+question);
>                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>                 map.put(TAG_QUES,question);
>                 System.out.println("questionMap:"+map);
>                 ques1.add(question);
> ```

```
                String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
                System.out.println("Checking ::"+answer);
                HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map1.put(TAG_ANSW, answer);
                System.out.println("AnswerMap:"+map1);
                answ1.add(answer);
```

I want to get these two hashmap values(TAG_QUESID and TAG_ANSW) in a single hashmap in a single key eg):  if i have map3 and i print map3 i should print these two values..
How to do this? because based upon the questionid i should get the answers,i want to increment the questionid for next question. plz help me..

Comment: HashMap<String, String[]> map2 = new HashMap<String, String[]>(); you can probably figure out the rest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is a java question. There are many ways you can do this.

1. `HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();`
2. `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();`
3. Create a class or enum(preferred) for example TAG, which has two string fields, then
   `Map<String, TAG> map = new HashMap<String, TAG>();`

Since your updated question is a little bit unclear, I tried to answer this based on my own understanding. I think what you want to do is continously getting questions and their answers.

So may be you can try another approach:

```
class Question{
    String questionText;
    String answer;
    ...
}

//map from questionID to a question
Map<String, Question> questionMap = new HashMap<String, Question>();
//TODO: fill up the map with existing questions.
Question question = questionMap.get(questionID);
System.out.println("Question:" + question.questionText + " Answer:" + question.answer);
//same for another question
```

Comment: based upon the questionid i should get the answers and futher i should increment the questionid for next question. so i need both the values in a single hashmap and i should increment it for next question .how to do this?

Comment: I want to increment the map for next question..Based upon the questionid i should get the question and answers.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about your question, can you give some sample input and sample output for your program?

Comment: yes if i click on next button i should increment the questionid and i should get next question based upon questionid...

Comment: Sorry, the site is blocked by Chinese Gov...Damn GFW, Will my updated answer help you?

Comment: pastebin.com is blocked in China because of the censorship policy by Chinese Government. Can you copy and paste it to this question?

Comment: From the code you provided, can you explain why you put the question and the answer into different maps? Why not a list/array/map of (question, answer) pairs?

Answer (score 1):

Use value separated by delimiters and split them later.

```
HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put(TAG_ANSW, ""+answer+":"+"questionid");
```

Then when you retrieve it just split them:

```
x= map1.get(TAG_ANSW)
String [] ans_questionId = x.split();
```

store them to their respective values...

Comment: based upon the questionid i should get the answers and futher i should increment the questionid for next question. so i need both the values in a single hashmap and i should increment it for next question .how to do this?

Comment: Can you give some sample scenario... some example can help!

Comment: I want to increment the map for next question..Based upon the questionid i should get the question and answers...

Answer (score 0):

```
 HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> multiMap = 
   new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

 void put(String key, String value) {
     ArrayList<String> values = multiMap.get(key);
     if (values == null) {
        values = new ArrayList<String>();
        multiMap.put(values);
     }
     values.add(value); 
 }

 ArrayList<String> get(String key) {
   ArrayList<String> value = multiMap.get(key);
   return value;
 }

 // Need to specify also which value to remove
 void remove(String key, String value) {
   ArrayList<String> values = multiMap.get(key);
   if (values != null) {
      values.remove(value);
      if (values.size() == 0)
        multiMap.remove(key);
   }
 }
```

If you do not want to keep repetitive values for the same key, use `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`. In any case you get back a collection of all values you have ever stored under this key.

Comment: based upon the questionid i should get the answers and futher i should increment the questionid for next question. so i need both the values in a single hashmap and i should increment it for next question .how to do this?

Comment: I want to increment the map for next question..Based upon the questionid i should get the question and answers.

Comment: Do not understand. Howe can you increment a *map*? It is only possible to increment a number.

Comment: Then how i should implement this..based upon the questionid i should get answers..in hashmap..and i should increment the question to get next question and answers please help me