# How to implement mixture of Strings and SpannableStrings in ArrayList without loads of additional code

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

Is it possible to have a mixture of both `String` and `SpannableString` in an `ArrayList` without adding loads of code?

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        // SpannableStrings
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        SpannableString str1 = new SpannableString(" Hello World ");
        str1.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, str1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.circle)), 0, str1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ssb.append(str1);

        SpannableString str2 = new SpannableString(" Bonjour le monde");
        str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, str2.length(), 0);
        ssb.append(str2);

        data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(ssb);
        data.add(getString(R.string.section_b));
        data.add(getString(R.string.section_c));

        subdata = new ArrayList<>();
        subdata.add("Item A1");
        subdata.add("Item B1\nItem B2");
        subdata.add("Item C1\nItem C2\nItem C3");


        adapter = createAdapter();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Spannable> data;
    ArrayList<String> subdata;
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> adapter;
}
```

Comment: Please see the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446776/how-to-add-spannablestring-to-a-list-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both String and SpanableString implement CharSequence. If you don't need data that CharSequence can't give you, you can just use that.

```
data = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not place the two string on the same index on an array, but Use hash_map for that,
 you can get the same result as you want. follow this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561875/how-to-get-two-values-of-string-in-a-single-hashmap) , hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve that would be to create

```
ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can then add any object to the ArrayList
Hope this helps:)